# filling dataframe column with values from another dataframe meeting certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have two dataframes:

prices

```
date        price   currency    rate
13-04-2018  34      EUR 
14-04-2018  23      USD 
15-04-2018  64      PLN
```

exchange_rates

```
date        currency    rate
13-04-2018  EUR         4
13-04-2018  USD         3
13-04-2018  PLN         1
13-04-2018  EUR         3,9
13-04-2018  USD         2,8
13-04-2018  PLN         1
13-04-2018  EUR         4,3
13-04-2018  USD         3,2
13-04-2018  PLN         1
```

I want to add column in prices DF with rate taken from exchangerates dataframe... correct rate should be selected (for the right date and right currency). I tried with match(), np.where and iloc but have not succeeded.

Comment: have you try merge ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

prices = <ur prices dataset> 
exchange_rates = <ur exchange rates dataset> 
output = pd.merge(prices, exchange_rates, on=["date", "currency"], how="inner")
print(output)
```